How can we solve the problem caused by the version in Flutter stripe integration?
While trying to add the flutter_stripe library to my Flutter project, I am experiencing a conflict with the flutter_compass library. This can often be caused by conflicting package dependencies or version incompatibilities. How can I resolve this conflict with the flutter_compass library to seamlessly include the flutter_stripe library in the project? If you have any suggestions or solutions, please share them.
Footnote: I did not install the flutter_compass library myself, it was installed through a library I used.
Thanks.


It said: "namespace not specified"

I don't know what the error actually means but it doesn't look like it has anything to do with conflicting dependencies

I understand that it says the namespace is not specified, but I think it wants me to specify it in the module's build file, I don't quite understand that. I specify the namespace in my own build file.
